# Got Error "Xcode got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." when duplicate target with apple script

Tags: xcode5, applescript

I have written an script for duplicate target of Xcode project and got Error "Xcode got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.

My script is:

```
 tell application "Xcode"
activate
delay 3
tell active workspace document
    set my_project to (get first project)
    tell my_project
        set make_target to (get first target of my_project)
        set target_name to "ScriptDemoCopy"
        tell application "System Events"

            keystroke "d" using {command down}

            --set my_new_target to make target with data make_target with properties {name:target_name}
        end tell

    end tell

end tell
```

end tell
Can someone tell me where am i wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may find what your looking for here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694750/how-to-automate-creation-of-new-xcode-targets-from-applescript-automator-shell-s

Comment: There is a clear sentence "Duplicate an existing target and rename it (not implemented)", So I have not tried that one :)

Comment: ok so maybe that says that you have to go the long way about it , or that it's not possible

Comment: In that case I need proper documentation that says it is not possible. :(

Comment: I wrote a script for a client which duplicates targets by scripting the interface. Once you accurately select the target(the hard part), you can use keystroke "d" using command down

Comment: @user123456 if only people would document the things that are not possible ;)

Comment: @adayzdone can you tell me where am i doing wrong?, I doubt i am using wrong way to set the target_name but not sure how to do this, I have no idea about apple script :(

Comment: @adayzdone even also I have tried with command line but not succeed :(

Comment: @user123456 You need to script the interface with System Events to send keystrokes and reference/select UI elements. It is far from ideal, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for guidance but still could not get how to select one the options of popup getting with these command keystroke "d" using {command down}

Comment: @adayzdone btw in which Xcode version have you written Script?

Comment: I am editing my question by which I am getting alert but don't know how select duplicate only?

Comment: @adayzdone You have used apple script right, Please look my question edited.

Comment: @adayzdone Can you show the code to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58349/discussion-between-user123456-and-adayzdone).